# Java add to element already in arrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, addition

I've got an `ArrayList<String>` and want to add to a string already in it, but not replace it. Is this possible without `myArrayList.set(index, myArrayList.get(index) + "myString");`? From my understanding, `myArrayList.get(index) += "myString";` does not work because it is read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `myArrayList.get(index) += "myString";` does not work because you are never storing it back in arraylist. Due to [immutability of strings](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/string-immutability-in-java/), your new string is created but it is not referred. Hence you don't find it reflected in arraylist element.

Personally, I would have chosen the first way.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in java are immutable.  The involvement of an ArrayList is irrelevant to the issue.  You could use an ArrayList< StringBuilder > for your use case, I guess.

```
myArray.get( i ).append( "foo" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is a  **immutable** class ,so you can not do it , if you add an element ,you can call  `myArrayList.add(element)` or `myArrayList.add(index, element)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`

For example,

```
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    int index = 0;
    list.add(new StringBuilder(""));
    System.out.println(list.get(index));
    list.get(index).append("once");
    System.out.println(list.get(index));
    list.get(index).append("-twice");
    System.out.println(list.get(index));
```